# I'm not able to fetch records from this NHibernate mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

  <class name="CITI.manageID.Data.Entities.AuthUserKioskRoleMap,CITI.manageID.Data" table="AuthUserKioskRoleMap" lazy="false">
    <composite-id name="Id" class="CITI.manageID.Data.Entities.AuthUserKioskRoleMapId,CITI.manageID.Data">
      <key-many-to-one name="AuthUsers" class="CITI.manageID.Data.Entities.AuthUsers,CITI.manageID.Data" column="UserID" />
      <key-many-to-one name="KioskInfo" class="CITI.manageID.Data.Entities.KioskInfo,CITI.manageID.Data" column="KioskID" />
      <key-many-to-one name="AuthRole" class="CITI.manageID.Data.Entities.AuthRole,CITI.manageID.Data" column="Roleid" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Status" column="Status" type="string" />
    <property name="CreatedBy" column="CreatedBy" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="CreatedOn" column="CreatedOn" type="DateTime" not-null="true" />
    <property name="UpdatedBy" column="UpdatedBy" type="string" />
    <property name="UpdatedOn" column="UpdatedOn" type="DateTime" />
    <many-to-one name="AuthRole" column="Roleid" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="AuthUsers" column="UserID" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="KioskInfo" column="KioskID" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have tried following

```
ICriteria crit = SessionRepository.CreateRepositoryCriteria(typeof(AuthUserKioskRoleMap));
crit.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("AuthUsers.Userid", AuthUserID));
crit.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("KioskInfo.Kioskid", KioskID));
crit.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Id.AuthUsers.Status", "A"));
crit.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Id.KioskInfo.Status", "A"));
crit.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Id.AuthRole.Status ", "A"));
crit.Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Status", "A"));
crit.AddOrder(new Order("ImageType", true));

ApplicantFaceInfoList = crit.List<AuthUserKioskRoleMap>();
```

Please Help

Comment: If you're **able to fetch** the data - what's the question?? What's your issue??

Comment: I suspect the title should be "I am `NOT` able to fetch..." I vote to reopen. IMO S.O. users sometimes judges to quickly.

Comment: @sanjay - Should the title be "I `cannot` fetch the data.." ?

Comment: I think the omitted 'not' here was rather obvious and accidental. I'm re-opening this.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you have any rows in your database that match your query?

Answer (score 0):

Is this mapping file called `AuthUserKioskRoleMap.hbm.xml` and is set as an embeddable object in Visual Studio?

Notice the hbm.xml extension as this is important.

If this still does not work then please provide more information e.g. any errors and/or the configuation code.